# Image rotation and translation using an aruco marker

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, 3d, aruco

I am trying to warp an image based of the orientation of the camera relative to an aruco marker in the middle of the image. I have managed to get the translation part working but the rotation element is not working. [image] It seems like the image isn't rotating about the centre of the aruco axis. The reference image was taken straight on and the warped image is overlayed.

```py
# Find centre of the marker
top_left_x = (corners[0][0][0, 0])
top_left_y = (corners[0][0][0, 1])
top_right_x = (corners[0][0][1, 0])
top_right_y = (corners[0][0][1, 1])
bottom_right_x = (corners[0][0][2, 0])
bottom_right_y = (corners[0][0][2, 1])
bottom_left_x = (corners[0][0][3, 0])
bottom_left_y = (corners[0][0][3, 1])
# Compare this to the centre of the image to calculate the offset
mid_x = top_right_x - (top_right_x - top_left_x) / 2  
mid_y = bottom_left_y - (bottom_left_y - top_left_y) / 2
x_centre = 960
y_centre = 540
x_offset = x_centre - mid_x
y_offset = y_centre - mid_y
if x_centre > mid_x:  # gone right
    x_offset = 1 * (x_centre - mid_x)  # correction to the left
if x_centre < mid_x:  # gone left
    x_offset = -1 * (mid_x - x_centre)  # correction to the right

if y_centre > mid_y:  # gone down
    y_offset = 1 * (y_centre - mid_y)  # correction to the left
if y_centre < mid_y:  # gone left
    y_offset = -1 * (mid_y - y_centre)  # correction to the right
current_z_distance = (math.sqrt((pos_camera[0]**2) + (pos_camera[1]**2) + 
(pos_camera[2]**2))) * 15.4

img = cv2.imread('Corrected.png')
corrected_z = 31  # Distance when image was taken
initial_z_distance = corrected_z * 15.4  # Pixels

delta_z = (initial_z_distance - current_z_distance)
scale_factor = current_z_distance / initial_z_distance # how much larger the image 
now is. Used for scaling

z_translation = delta_z * 1.54  # how much the image has moved. negative for going 
backwards
z_translation = 0
z_axis = 960 / scale_factor 

proj2dto3d = np.array([[1, 0, -mid_x],
                        [0, 1, -mid_y],
                        [0, 0, 0],
                        [0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

proj3dto2d = np.array([[z_axis, 0, mid_x, 0],
                        [0, z_axis, mid_y, 0],  # defines to centre of rotation
                        [0, 0, 1, 0]], np.float32)

trans = np.array([[1, 0, 0, x_offset * -1], # Working
                  [0, 1, 0, y_offset * -1],
                  [0, 0, 1, 960],  # keep as 960
                  [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

x = math.degrees(roll_marker) * -1  # forwards and backwards
y = math.degrees(pitch_marker) * -1  # Left and right
z = 0
rx = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)  #

ry = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)

rz = np.array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
               [0, 1, 0, 0],
               [0, 0, 1, 0],
               [0, 0, 0, 1]], np.float32)
ax = float(x * (math.pi / 180.0))  # 0
ay = float(y * (math.pi / 180.0))
az = float(z * (math.pi / 180.0))  # 0

rx[1, 1] = math.cos(ax)  # 0
rx[1, 2] = -math.sin(ax)  # 0
rx[2, 1] = math.sin(ax)  # 0
rx[2, 2] = math.cos(ax)  # 0

ry[0, 0] = math.cos(ay)
ry[0, 2] = -math.sin(ay)
ry[2, 0] = math.sin(ay)
ry[2, 2] = math.cos(ay)

rz[0, 0] = math.cos(az)  # 0
rz[0, 1] = -math.sin(az)  # 0
rz[1, 0] = math.sin(az)  # 0
rz[1, 1] = math.cos(az)  # 0

#  Translation matrix

#  r = rx.dot(ry)  # if we remove the lines we put    r=ry
r = rx.dot(ry) # order may need to  be changed
final = proj3dto2d.dot(trans.dot(r.dot(proj2dto3d)))  # just rotation
dst = cv2.warpPerspective(img, final, (img.shape[1], img.shape[0]), None, cv2.INTER_LINEAR, cv2.BORDER_CONSTANT, (255, 255, 255))
```

Comment: all of that strikes me as needlessly convoluted. let's start fresh. -- where is your rvec and tvec? you need to realize that the transformation expressed by rvec and tvec transforms points from marker-frame-local to camera-frame-local, i.e. it expresses the marker's pose relative to the camera's frame. -- you could simply take the corners of the marker, and work with `getPerspectiveTransform`, then add some translation in screen space to put the marker's center in the image's center.

Comment: remember to use numpy's matrix multiplication (infix `@` operator), not elementwise multiplication. and don't touch individual elements of matrices so much. write utility functions that calculate individual transformations, then compose them using matrix multiplication. use `np.eye` for identity matrices, and as a basis for all transformations in which you change individual elements (last column for translation, diagonal for scaling, top left 2x2 or 3x3 block for rotations)

Comment: The rvec and tvec come from the aruco.drawAxis. What I'm trying to do is move the camera around and keep the overlayed image over the background (printed) image.